# Less extend error with simpless

Tags: less

I try this example:
[LESS differences between mixin and extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523551/less-differences-between-mixin-and-extend)

```
.black-text {
  color: #000000;
}
.title {
  &:extend(.black-text);
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

but the compiler simpless produces an error:
sintax error on line `&:extend(.black-text);`

why is this happening?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: i used simpless, but it works bad, so i delete it and install koala.
koala works perfect and no problems with "extend" in less, sass or scss.
so the problem was resolved.

Comment: So Koala doesn't work :(
You'd better to see at gulp/grunt or webpack plugins to compile less or scss. Gulp - https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less grunt - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less

Comment: >>> So Koala doesn't work


>>> install koala. koala works perfect and no problems with "extend" in less, sass or scss

>>> ou'd better to see at gulp/grunt
why?

I do not use programs that run from the command line.
and, after the comparison, I decided not to use less, only scss.
so i have not any problems with koala.